# the second wordpress is not working in docker

Tags: docker

I am learning the docker technology.
I run two wordpress in docker at one host. but the second wordpress is not good for working.
I run one mysql server in docker and the two wordpresss share the sample mysql.
run docker server command at below:

```
sudo docker run --name mysql_db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxx -d mysql

sudo docker run --name wordpress1 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress1 --link 
mysql_db:mysql -p 8008:80 -d wordpress

sudo docker run --name wordpress2 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress2 --link 
mysql_db:mysql -p 8009:80 -d wordpress
```

when I get the ip:8008 in IE, it is good,but get ip:8009, it redirect the ip:8008, i cann't get webpage from 8009 port.

So i look the second wordpress log, it show the http 302 error.

when I modify the 8009 to the 9009 and run the mysql and two wordpress in docker again, the second wordpress server is good, I can get webpage from ip:9009.

my mysql and wordpress image pull from the default office site.

so i cann't know when i modify the port 8009 to 9009, the second wordpress is working good. i cann't find the result through search.

## docker --version

Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

## uname -a

Linux linux-1 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

thks.

Comment: What is the site url set for those two setups?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is due to wordpress configuration and not something related to docker itself.

Comment: Also consider using something like `jwilder/nginx-proxy` instead of mapping each wordpress instance to localhost on some random port. You want both wordpress instances to serve using port 80/443 and that doesn't work unless you use a reverse proxy. (It's surprisingly easy to set up)

Answer (score 0):

I think i find the reason.
I try more other ports to wordpress mapping , only the 8009 is not ok.
Because my docker is in public cloud host, i must through the firewall to get my web server, so i think the 8009 is reflected to 8008 in firewall. 
It is not issue of docker and wordpress.
thanks all.